# C# ordering array of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of strings that are formated as `"ColX=Name=Value"`, where X is a number and X >= 4.

I'd like to sort the array in ascending order of that X, I tried using
`int colNbr = int.parse(string.Split('=')[0].Substring(3))`
to retreive the value of X, but then I don't know how to order the strings :/

Any easier recommendations appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there with the logic, just wanted to make a try with OrderBy. Following code will help you to complete that?

```
List<string> inputList = SomeMethod(); // will populate the list
inputList = inputList.OrderBy(x=> int.parse(x.Split('=')[0].Substring(3))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try working with *classes* (anonymous ones in the context), not raw `string`s:

```
string[] source = ...

var data = source
  .Select(line => line.Split('='))
  .Select(items => new {           // Let's have classes
      Col = int.Parse(items[0].Substring(3)),
      Name = items[1],
      Value = items[2], })
  .OrderBy(item => item.Col);     // ... which are easy to handle (e.g. sort)
```

Please, notice that if you decide to, say, sort by `Name` within the given `Col` all you have to do is to add `.ThenBy(item => item.Name)`: classes are easy to maintain.

If you want to get the `string[]` back:

```
string[] sorted = data
  .Select(item => $"Col{item.Col},{item.Name},{item.Value}")
  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could you OrderBy extension method.

```
 string[] sortedArrayString = arrayOfString
   .OrderBy(str => int.parse(str.Split('=')[0].Substring(3)))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the most in line with what I'm already working on, I'm trying this.